# Set start of a video as texture for PIXI sprite

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am working on an application that loads both images and videos using [PIXI.loaders.Loader](https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.loaders.Loader.html). If the resource is an image, the following code loads an image resource on a sprite and displays it on the renderer view:

```
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var texture = PIXI.loader.resources[<resource-name>].texture;
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
stage.addChild(sprite);
```

But if the resource is a video, the above code is not working, even though one of the first things I want to do is display the starting frame of the video as an image. Following that, I would like another part of the user interface to display a playing video.

Comment: You can draw frames from videos to canvas and you can export images from canvases, so you just put those two together.

Comment: How do I draw a frame from a video? Also, there is another wrinkle - I need to display a thumbnail of the video in another part of the application as a static image, and for that I am not using an actual canvas but expected to use a simply `<img>` tag .